# Apache - Passing query string to custom error page from an ErrorDocument redirect

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, errordocument

I have a custom error page that is just HTML/CSS and some JS that will take the query string (?error=404 for example) and display dynamic content based on that query string, with a generic fallback if none is supplied. I want this query string to be passed by the .htaccess ErrorDocument redirect but unfortunately it does not.

ErrorDocument 404 /error.html?error=404

This displays the generic error page as I assume it is truncating the query string. It does return a 404 status however, which is what I need.

I could obviously redirect to the absolute URL and maintain the query string but then I'd get a 200 header, which is no good!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this technique only to always use the same page with all error codes, but find the correct code (in your case `404`), you will always find this code in the variable (php): **$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]**

Comment: This is a much better way of doing what I was trying to do, I probably should have gone the PHP route to start.